# How can I send keys for different arrays in VueJs 3

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3

**I have two different Json Array**

```
search_types: {
        0: { name: 'BEGIN ::..', svalue: 1 },
        1: { name: '..:: END', svalue: 2 }
      }

other_dummy_data: {
        0: { id_company: 25, name: 'SHIMIT Co.' },
        0: { id_company: 26, name: 'BIG SHIMIT Co.' },
      }
```

**and I have a Component**

```
<template>
    <select
      :id="input_id"
      :value="modelValue"
      @input="$event => $emit('update:modelValue', $event.target.value)"
      >
    <option v-for="get in optArr" 
      :value="get.opt_value<<-- THE PROBLEM IS HEREM >>" 
      :key="get">{{ get.opt_name <<-- THE PROBLEM IS HEREM  }}</option>
    </select>

</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'InputSelect',
  props: {
    optArr: Array,
    opt_value: String,
    opt_name: String,
    input_id: String,
    modelValue: String
  }
}
</script>
```

I want to use the same component for two different JSON Arrays. But in the above example the probe that says << THE PROBLEM IS HERE >> is different for each JSON Array.

I tried as below but I am getting error.

```
<InputSelect 
v-model="sample_second_selected"
:optarr="search_types" 
:opt_name="name" 
:opt_value="svalue"/>


<InputSelect 
v-model="sample_selected"
:optarr="other_dummy_data" 
:opt_name="name" 
:opt_value="id_company"/>
```

Could you please help with this?
Thank you in advance for all your help.

Answer (score 1):

First off, note this is an object with numeric keys, not an array:

```
{
  0: { name: 'BEGIN ::..', svalue: 1 },
  1: { name: '..:: END', svalue: 2 }
}
```

this is an array:

```
[{ name: 'BEGIN ::..', svalue: 1 }, { name: '..:: END', svalue: 2 }]
```

and a JSON is a string (containing **J**ava**S**cript **O**bject **N**otation):

```
const json = '[{ "name": "BEGIN ::..", "svalue": 1 }, { "name": "..:: END", "svalue": 2 }]'
```

So what you called a JSON array is neither JSON nor an array. No worries, but these terms are so basic, you will do yourself a huge favor by getting them right.

---

I think you want to pass in the object or array (Vue's `v-for` can handle both) and a property name from the objects you loop over (in `opt_name`).

To resolve a property by name on an object, use bracket notation, i.e. in your template, do:

```
{{ get[opt_name] }}
```

If `opt_name` is a variable containing the string `"name"`, `myObject[opt_name]` is the same as writing `myObject.name`.

---

Since I am doing Mr. smarty pants anyway, some more tips:

- `get` is an inappropriate name for an object, not just because "get" is a verb, but because of its specific meaning in programming (I'm actually surprised that it is not a reserved keyword)
- `:key` has to be a primitive (basically string or number), but you pass in the object
- it is customary in Javascript to use camelCase for variables and properties, not snake_case - for most developers, this is not optional

Hope it helps

Comment: I'm no expert in this, but also, wouldn't `:opt_name="name"` and `:opt_value="id_company"` have to be written as `opt_name="name"` and `opt_value="id_company"` since the String value passed in is what matters to the prop, not the reactive value that it represents, and similarly for the other component declaration.

Comment: Dear Moritz Ringler,
Thank you for your suggestions, I will consider them in my next works. I will especially prefer "item" over "get" (:

You are right about JSON but I wrote it in a hurry because Vue-Devtools also assigns indexes to JSONs.

By the way, thanks to the square brackets, my problem was solved, thank you very much for your help.

While "item.opt_name" is not working, "item[opt_name]" works fine.